# Insert large asp.net control data row wise into sql table using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

Below is my 46 asp.net control including textboxes and dropdownlist to insert data in single button[image]

Below is my asp.net control id as above image given image

```
ddl_tag1    txt_date1   ddl_type1   txt_narration1   txt_amount1     txt_bill1   txt_fromloc1      txt_tolocation1
ddl_tag2    txt_date2   ddl_type2   txt_narration2   txt_amount2     txt_bill2   txt_fromloc2      txt_tolocation2
ddl_tag3    txt_date3   ddl_type3   txt_narration3   txt_amount3     txt_bill3   txt_fromloc3      txt_tolocation3
ddl_tag4    txt_date4   ddl_type4   txt_narration4   txt_amount4     txt_bill4   txt_fromloc4      txt_tolocation4
ddl_tag5    txt_date5   ddl_type5   txt_narration5   txt_amount5     txt_bill5   txt_fromloc5      txt_tolocation5
ddl_tag6    txt_date6   ddl_type6   txt_narration6   txt_amount6     txt_bill6   txt_fromloc6      txt_tolocation6
```

below is my table structure the above six row data insert one by one into below format

```
Sno    TAQ     DATE TYPE   NARRATION   AMOUNT     BILL   FROM LOCATIOM   TO LOCATION
```

What is the best way to insert data using add button, i have to use for each loop for insertion for above text boxes and drop-down to insertion one row then another row insertion.

Comment: Have you considered a GridView?

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually putting a bunch of controls onto a page, and not databinding them to anything, creating six manual insert statements is pretty much the only option as far as I know.

As one commenter said above, a gridview might be easier, but honestly if the point is solely just to add and not to also display/update (which is what gridviews are best at) I'm not sure how much that would gain you. If the requirement is specifically and only to add six new rows at a time, you're probably doing the easiest thing.

If you ultimately want more functionality than just add records, you may want to take a look at gridview though.